# Adding shortcut to favorites programmatically in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, shortcut, finder

I've built a Mac App and I want to add a shortcut to it within the favorites section of Finder on install. I do see other Apps achieving the same thing (such as AirDrop). How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by appleScript, however this is not the best way.(If cmd+t is changed to someother function, this will fail)

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    -- Select the path you want on the sidebar in the Finder
    select folder "Preferences" of folder "Library" of (path to home folder)
    tell application "System Events"
        -- Command-T adds the Documents Folder to the sidebar
        keystroke "t" using command down
    end tell
end tell
```

Also, you can add an item by using [LSSharedFileList](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/pyobjc/pyobjc-26/pyobjc/pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices/PyObjCTest/test_lssharedfilelist.py).

Comment: THanks, this is useful but this is just adding a folder. not adding an external drive which is what I am after (sorry was not clear on that i the original post).